# WPF - Acessar UserControl de uma TabItem selecionada

Tags: c#, wpf

Possuo um *TabControl* com diversas *TabItems*, que separei o conteúdo em *UserControls* para organizar o código. Mas todas eles tem um *TextBox* em comum do qual eu quero obter o valor em um Button na *MainWindow*.

Eu sou novo em *WPF*, ainda estou aprendendo, pensei em expor o valor do *TextBox* em uma propriedade pública em cada *UserControl*, daí então obter o *TabItem* selecionado (`(TabItem)TabControlMain.SelectedItem`), e obter o objeto *UserControl* interno para acessar tal propriedade (poderia usar uma interface com um método Get). O problema é que não consigo obter esse *UserControl*, não sei como fazer.

Gostaria de saber como fazer algo do tipo, ou, se essa for uma solução inadequada ao *WPF*, gostaria de saber como poderia estruturar meu código para um caso desses: vários *TabItems* e obter valores internos desde a janela que possui o *TabControl*, preferencialmente separando por arquivos (como com *UserControls*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema!

Abaixo um esboço que demonstra minha solução:

```
var tabSelecionada = (TabItem)TabControlMain.SelectedItem;
var uc = (IInterfaceComGet)tabSelecionada.Content;
var resultado = uc.MétodoGetDaInterface();
```

E no UserControl:

```
public partial class MeuUserControl : UserControl, IInterfaceComGet { ... }
```

Basicamente, minha dificuldade foi por desconhecer a propriedade `Content`.